# Multiple Errors in Hangman program

Tags: python-2.7, 2d-games

I've been teaching my self to program in python lately and decided to make this game. I have been successful for the majority of it except for a few things

1. When an incorrect letter is inputted, the letter is appended to the wrong letter array for as many spots in the gamespace array that the userletter does equal.Example: if I type in "the" for the wordtarget, I get t, h and e printed 2 times into wrong letter array. No matter what the letter gets out into wrong letter array

Code:

```
wordTarget = raw_input("enter word here: ").lower ()
gameSpace = ["_"] * Len(wordTarget)
wrongLetter = []
def main():
    for x in range(0, len(wordTarget)):    
        while (gameSpace[x] !=     wordTarget[x]):
            getLetter()
            for i in range(0,len(wordTarget)):
                if (wordTarget[i] == userLetter):
                    gameSpace[i] = userLetter
                elif (wordTarget[i] != userLetter):
                    print "letter is incorrect, try again"
                    wrongLetter.append(userLetter)
            print ("Incorrect Letters: %s" % wrongLetter)
            print ("Correct Letters: %s" % gameSpace)
            if (gameSpace == wordTarget):
                print "Congratulations! You won"                
main()
```

I'm guessing the problem lies with the for loops I'm running and the way I'm checking for right answer but can't figure it out.

Comment: You need to add _the relevant_ part of your code in _your question_. Not _all_ of your code and not link to some off-site place.

Comment: How are the `gameSpace` and `wordTarget` values set up? Are they strings, lists  or something else?

Comment: gameSpace is an array which stores the empty spaces and letters if guessed correctly. wordTarget is user input and Is a variable.

Comment: Um, by "array" do you mean `list` (e.g. `["a", "b", "c"]`) or just a string of characters like `"abc"`? And really, the same question about `wordTarget`, regardless of where it came from. What's its type? If you're not sure you have the Python vocabulary to explain with words (perfectly understandable for a beginner), please show the code that sets those variables up.

Comment: gamespace is a list that is composed of underscores for each letter of the word. wordTarget is just a string

Comment: If `gameSpace` is a list and `wordTarget` is a string, you can compare them with `while ("".join(gameSpace) != wordTarget):`.

Comment: So I wouldn't need the first for loop?

Comment: That's true. I am also looking at the second loop, and think you need to change it to a `while` loop using the `wordTarget.find() function. Give me a minute.

Comment: I added the change and it still keeps updating the wrongLetter list with everything letter multiple time depending on the amount of empty spaces in front of it. Ex: if I enter hello as word and h as first letter, I get the letter h put into wrongletter list 4 times. If I enter the as word and t as letter, t is out into wrongletter list 2 times

Comment: You get multiple entries in the wrongLetter list because you are using a for loop. That loop checks every letter in the target, and add an entry to wrongLetter for each non-matching character in the target.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that earlier but I wasn't sure how to stop it from checking the rest of the letters after it finds one wrong letter

Answer (score 0):

The loop checking the letter seems to be your issue. Try replacing it with:

```
        position = 0
        ptr = wordTarget.find(userLetter, position)
        while ptr != -1:
            gameSpace[ptr] = userLetter
            position = ptr + 1
            ptr =  wordTarget.find(userLetter, position)

        if position == 0: # no match ever found
            print "letter is incorrect, try again"
            wrongLetter.append(userLetter)
```

Also replace the original for loop with `while ("".join(gameSpace) != wordTarget):`, and you should be good to go.

Comment: The wordTarget variable is where the word is stored not the letter. Give me a second and I'll post the getletter code on here

Comment: I assumed that the value in userLetter was the entered letter. If that is true, then `wordTarget.find(position, userLetter)` means "Look in the string wordTarget, starting at position, and find the next instance of userLetter." The code in the answer starts immediately after the `getLetter()` function call.

Comment: I editited the code and got the error: ptr =wordTarget.Find(position, userletter). Attribute error: 'str' object has no attribute 'Find'

Comment: Arrgh - typo. `Find` should be `find`. I mostly code in SQL Server, which has no case sensitivity.

Comment: Another error. Same line except now it says slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__method

Comment: "Bother, bother bother" said Poo.  I suspect I used the find syntax from another language and not Python. One moment... Ah. I reversed parameters. It should be `ptr = wordTarget.Find(userLetter, position)'

Comment: I edited the original code above to correct the case and the parameter positions.

Comment: Glad to help. Don't forget to vote up those who helped.

Comment: If you have time could you explain to me why my code didn't work and yours did. I'm curious to know why

Comment: The issue was in your inner `for` loop. you tested each and every letter in `wordTarget` to see if it matched the letter in `userLetter`. **If** you had had some mechanism that tracked if you ever matched a letter, and only appended your letter to `wrongLetter` if none matched, then you would have only one copy of the letter in `wrongLetter`. However, you appended the letter to `wrongLetter` each time you found a letter that didn't match, instead of checking to see if any letters had matched. That's what my code does - checks to see if any characters matched before appending to `wrongLetter`.

Comment: That makes sense now. I was trying to figure out a way of doing it but I couldnt